# Organising sibling divs in parent div using css

Tags: html, css

So, I thought this would be a really simple process but it would appear not and Im really stumped now!  Here's the scenario:

I've got a parent div, inside that div are 3 more divs, the top Div is X pixels high 100% width, the bottom div is Z pixels high 100% width, I need the middle div to be the remainder height at all times left between the top and bottom divs (the content of the middle div can expand beyond the divs boundaries so I need to be able to put a scrollbar in it) and the parent div is resizeable.

I thought I'd be able to work this out pretty easily but it appears not!  Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this would be greatly appreciated as I cant get it to work at all!

Comment: Give us some code and we give you some help... As easy as this ;)

Comment: Everything I can think of, I've tried using positions, setting the parent div to absolute and the top div to absolute, the bottom div is set to absolute bottom 0 and those stay in place but no matter what I try on the middle div it wont budge or stay at the height diff :/

Answer (score 0):

[`flexbox`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) to the rescue.

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 700px;
}

.one{
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.two{
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.three{
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="one">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like it should do exactly what I want, but it doesnt work for some reason, would having things like position in the parent cause issues with flexbox? :/

Comment: Possibly. I can't tell just from that.

Comment: I think the issue is also clouded by the fact that the middle box starts empty and thus has no height, the parent div is also re-sizeable and I want the middle box to resize to fill the gap between the top and bottom divs that have fixed heights... :(